# How to exports all vm's in two subscription in .csv

Tags: powershell, azure

I am looking to build a script which exports all the vm's (Weather ASM OR ARM) in two subscriptions and writes all those into a .csv files where I can do further analysis on them can somebody explain me how to do this. Highly appreciative.

Comment: what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right, it is possible.

It depends on what information you want to export. It is easy for you to convert PowerShell result to .csv file. Just use `Export-Csv`. If you only want to list your VM, you could try to use the following commands.

```
##Example
$vms=get-azurermvm
$vms|Export-Csv "shui.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```